# Is it possible to have a rational function with an horizontal flex?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

My question is the follow:

> Is it possible to have a function of this type:
>   $$f(x)=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i}{\sum_{j=0}^mb_jx^j}$$
>   with the constraint that $\sum_{j=0}^m b_jx^j\not\equiv 1$ and of course $\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i\not\equiv 0$

that have an horizontal inflexion.

Comment: What is a "horizontal flex"? I don't know what a "flex" is, either.

Comment: I edit. Sorry. Inflexion @Ingix

Comment: Do you mean "horizontal inflection point"? Also, I suppose that you want the expression in the denominator to be non-zero.

Comment: And why not just take $f(x)=x^3$ (it can be written e.g. as $f(x)=\frac{2x^3}{2}$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I still misunderstand, but to me it looks like you want to find (or prove it can't exist) a rational function that has a point of inflection where the tangent is horizontal.

This is possible, for example at $x=0$ for

$f(x)=\frac{x^3}{x+1}.$

You can easily do the calculations for the derivatives yourself, or look at the follwoing picture to convince you.
[image]

Again, maybe that is not what you wanted.